# SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflow not working

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I am trying to call simple SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow on New Task Creation. There is nothing more then simple history log in workflow for testing purpose.

When I manually start new workflow I am getting following error.

```
RequestorId: feb139dc-d55e-4313-f619-e98c938efb2b. Details: 
System.ApplicationException: HTTP 404 The resource cannot be found.
Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
temporarily unavailable. &nbsp;Please review the following URL and make
sure that it is spelled correctly. Requested URL:
/ITech/BS/KM/_vti_bin/client.svc/web/lists/getbyid(guid&#39;73805f5a-9e13-47b7-8142-cfaf23adcd7a&#39;) {"Cache-Control":["private"],"Date":["Fri,
18 Nov 2016 11:17:15 GMT"],"Server":["Microsoft-IIS\/8.5"],"X-AspNet-Version":["4.0.30319"],"X-Powered-By":["ASP.NET"]} at
Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at
System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance,
ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at
System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

[image]

My SharePoint Designer 2010 workflow is working all fine. This is just issue with 2013 workflow.

Comment: The only action in the workflow is a log to the history list?  Is this a 2013-mode or 2010-mode workflow?  If it's the former, have 2013 workflows ever worked, or have you just flipped the switch on that and this is your first test?

Comment: Yes it just the log to history list. and this is 2013 workflow. There is another 2010 workflow on another list which is working well.

Comment: Is this the first 2013 workflow in your set up?

Comment: yes. it is the first 2013 workflow

Comment: Ok.  I think the most likely explanation is an issue with how your Workflow Manager server is set up.  The 404 error indicates it can't find the workflow history log to actually add anything to it.  I'm a developer in a big enough organization where developer and administrator are two separate roles, so I'm not sure I can offer any advice, but I'd definitely look to your workflow manager server's configuration.

Comment: Also, not for nothing, I'd honestly not use 2013 workflows at all, unless you've got some specific need for the looping or steps or whatever.  They've caused us nothing but headaches.